# Partner Community user are not able to see List view control icon

Tags: community, administration, community-builder, partner-communities, community-cloud

I have one query where Community users are not able to see the listview control icon, even with the assigned system permission to "Create and Customize List Views".

[image: Community User Listview Image]

Answer (score 0):

List views are visible to your Experience Cloud site users with Customer Community Plus, Partner Community, Lightning Platform Starter, and Lightning Platform Plus licenses, if the Visible to all users setting is enabled for views of objects in site user profiles. To make list views visible only to your Salesforce users, select Visible to certain groups of users. Then share the view with the All Internal Users group or a selected set of internal groups and roles.

When implementing an Experience Cloud site, create custom views that contain only relevant information for site users. Then make those views visible to site users by sharing them with the All Customer Portal Users group, or a set of site groups and roles.  Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customviews.htm&type=5).